# Do I need a team for each Concourse environment?

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

I am working with Concourse 5. There are 3 different environments in Amazon for my application: Develop, Staging and Production. Do I need to define 3 teams in Concourse too?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a separate team for a stage is not necessary unless we need user-role management. In most cases, the default team (main) is sufficient and preferred for usual functions.